# Directory hierarchy after index.php

Tags: php, url, directory

I believe this might be a lame question, but i found this url:

http://www.trickingpt.com/index.php/componentes/componente-artigos/tricks/basicmoves?id=125

The question is simple:

How is it possible for a url to have like a folder hierarchy after a php file and then the get parameter?

At first i thought it would be some script trick that i didn't know, but then i noticed this on the page that lead to the other referred above:

href="/index.php/componentes/componente-artigos/tricks/basicmoves?id=125"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple. The `index.php` is using `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` to read the path requested (the part after index.php) and then executes appropriate code to return the response.

It is very likely the website linked is using a framework that handles these urls and routes this "folder hierarchy" paths to respective controllers. Like, for example, does [Kohana framework](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole URL by getting $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].